Async Pipe is triggering after POST Request
I have a problem where my async pipe is triggering a GET request but i only want a post request to trigger and put the new element in the array. My function looks like the following:
  create(hersteller: Hersteller) {
    this.herstellerService.create(hersteller).subscribe((neuerHersteller) => {
      this.hersteller$ = this.hersteller$.pipe(
        map((hersteller) => [neuerHersteller, ...hersteller])
      );
    });
  }

In my html template i have the asnyc pipe:
...
[tableData]="(hersteller$ | async) ?? []"
...

The behavior is as follows: First, the POST request is sent. After that, the GET request is triggered, and I receive all the elements, including the new one. Then, I copy the new element, resulting in it being in the array twice.
Not copying the new element. Than its only once in the array, but the GET request is still triggering and reloads the table.
Edit init hersteller$:
  hersteller$: Observable<Hersteller[]>;

  constructor(
    private herstellerService: HerstellerService,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.hersteller$ = this.herstellerService.readAll();
  }


Can you please provide the code to show how is this.hersteller$ initialized?

Yeah sry, it edited

You are overriding the this.hersteller$ Observable after successful creation. This looks very odd to me and will likely cause unexpected behavior. You should find a solution where the original Observable stays the same, and you are just pushing new values to it. Maybe a Subject can help you with that.

The code you provided is working as it should, but it's far from optimal and not what you expect. What's the issue:
// You are initializing Observable with service call
// Async pipe will subscribe to it and handle the result
// That's OK
this.hersteller$ = this.herstellerService.readAll();

// But here, you are re-assigning it, now with pipe and mapping
// Async pipes unsubscribes the previous one an subscribe to new one
// This triggers the GET
this.hersteller$ = this.hersteller$.pipe(
  map((hersteller) => [neuerHersteller, ...hersteller])
);

In your case, you can change hersteller to synchronous property, subscribing manually and thus removing the async pipe.
hersteller: Hersteller = [];

constructor(
  private herstellerService: HerstellerService,
  private dialog: MatDialog
) {
  this.herstellerService.readAll().subscribe((hersteller) => {
    this.hersteller = hersteller;
  });
}

create(hersteller: Hersteller) {
  this.herstellerService.create(hersteller).subscribe((neuerHersteller) => {
    this.hersteller = [...this.hersteller, neuerHersteller];
    // Or maybe just with push, if neuerHersteller is not an Array
    // this.hersteller.push(neuerHersteller);
  });
}
// And in template
/*
...
[tableData]="hersteller"
...
*/

Sticking with asynchronous property is possible, but over-complicated in my opinion.
// BehaviorSubject gives you an access to its value
hersteller$: BehaviorSubject<Hersteller> = new BehaviorSubject<Hersteller>([]);

constructor(
  private herstellerService: HerstellerService,
  private dialog: MatDialog
) {
  this.herstellerService.readAll().subscribe((hersteller) => {
    // This is ugly, but doable
    this.hersteller$.next(hersteller);
  });
}

create(hersteller: Hersteller) {
  this.herstellerService.create(hersteller)
    .pipe(
      // Merge new value with hersteller current value
      map((neuerHersteller) => [...this.hersteller$.value, neuerHersteller])
    )
    .subscribe((neuerHersteller) => {
      this.hersteller$.next(neuerHersteller);
  });
}
// Template stays the same


I thought the good thing about async pipe is, that i dont have to handle the unsubscribe. Is there any downside with your approach?

async pipe automatically unsubscribes and triggers a change detection, so you are guaranteed that your changes will be reflected in the view. The same doesn't happen when working with synchronous variables. (without considering that generally reactive code is preferable since it's much more mantainable and rxjs is designed to produce reactive code)

@Pointless that's correct, async pipe in this case should help avoid issues with data updates. Problem is, that you can't update hersteller$by reassigning it's value, so you should use some Subject for that

It seems you are trying to append new results to an already existings Observable.
You should not reassign the observable value, but you should use a Subject to emit all new elements of the array, and you can use scan to put them into an array.
Here's an example of the pattern.
Let's break it down:

itemsSubj emits new Items, allowing you to add new Items to the array
items$ reacts to every itemsSubj emission, adding the Items emitted to its array (initially empty) thanks to the scan operator
factory emulates your service call returning an Observable<Item>
create takes the Observable<Item> and tells itemsSubj to emit it.

  itemsSubj = new Subject<Item>();
  items$ = this.itemsSubj.pipe(
    scan((acc: Item[], newItem: Item) => [...acc, newItem], [])
  );

  create() {
    this.factory().subscribe(item => this.itemsSubj.next(item))
  }

  factory() {
    this.itemNum++;
    return of({ num: this.itemNum });
  }

